# Python SQL - Trouble inserting into database. (NO error)

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, discord, asyncpg

```py
USER_ROBLOX_ID = 114678641
author_id = 257073333273624576
date_today = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
await self.bot.db.execute("""
INSERT INTO user_data (roblox_id, discord_id, verified_at, verify_code) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4);
""", USER_ROBLOX_ID, author_id, date_today, "Default")
```

For some reason, it makes an error but I don't know why, it won't let me insert it into my database.

This is the error on the date_today:

```
 ('str' object has no attribute 'toordinal')
```

Is there something wrong with the code? The connection works, the role I'm using is superuser so no permission stuff.

Comment: This is the error on the date_today `('str' object has no attribute 'toordinal')`

Comment: remove `.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')` on line 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

strptime() transform a datetime to a string. As you can see your error is about your str not having 'toordinal' attribute

strptime() is the opposite function, allow you to transform a string to a datetime.

As your column is set up to be a datetime, it will contain a full datetime object and you can't format it to '%Y-%m-%d' in database

You can round it to day using

```
dt = datetime(2013, 12, 14, 5, 0, 0)
dt = datetime(*dt.timetuple()[:3]) # 2013-12-14 00:00:00
```